# How to find the shops whose customers are only men?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this schema:

PERSON(Name, Sex)

FREQUENTS(Name, Shop)

My question is, how do I find the shops whose clients are exclusively men?

Comment: can you provide some example data?

Comment: Use a query that identifies each shop that has a female visitor, and use a NOT IN clause to exclude these from the `Frequents` table. Have a try _first_ and then ask for help, this isn't hard SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following using a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT frequents.shop
FROM frequents LEFT JOIN person ON frequents.name = person.name 
GROUP BY frequents.shop
HAVING SUM(person.sex = 'female') = 0 AND SUM(person.sex = 'male') > 0
```

> [**demo at dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86c36bc71482bf7cd4a2724666024c59)

Answer (score 0):

```
select shop
from
(select shop , (case when sex = 'Male' then 1 else 2 end)s_cnt
from frequents a11 
join person a12
on a11.name = a12.name
group by shop , (case when sex = 'Male' then 1 else 2 end)
) a11
group by shop
having sum(s_cnt) = 1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer (not to the comment section) such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

For example `NOT EXISTS`

```
select distinct shop
from frequents
where not exists (
    select 1
    from person
    where person.name = frequents.name and person.sex = 'female'
)
```

However, according to [this](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) test is may be better to use `IS NULL` approach:

```
select distinct shop
from frequents
left join person on person.name = frequents.name and person.sex = 'female'
where person.name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exclusively men, then I would think:

```
SELECT f.shop
FROM frequents f JOIN
     person p
     ON f.name = p.name 
GROUP BY f.shop
HAVING MIN(p.sex) = MAX(p.sex) AND  -- all sex values are the same or NULL
       COUNT(p.sex) = COUNT(*) AND  -- no NULL values
       MIN(p.sex) = 'male'          -- the value is male
```

This version does not assume that there are only two genders.